# Attribute Routing ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have been tried to know an attribute routing system in ASP.NET Core. I have following codes and would like to know why my Save Method in controller does not trigger on form post:-

HTML code:-

```
 <form method="post" action="/Address/Save">
        <label asp-for="Street">Street:</label>
        <input type="text" asp-for="Street" />
        <label asp-for="City">City:</label>
        <input type="text" asp-for="City" />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />      
    </form>
```

My address controller code follow:-

```
public class AddressController : Controller
{
    public List<Address> addresses { get; set; } = new List<Address>();

    [HttpGet()]
    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        return View(new Address());
    }
    [Route("/Address/Save")]
    [HttpPost()]
    public IActionResult Save([FromBody] Address address)
    {

       //codes removed for brevity

    }
    public IActionResult Privacy()
    {
        return View();
    }     
}
```

startup routing configuration

```
 app.UseMvc(routes =>
  {
    routes.MapRoute(
    name: "default",
    template: "{controller=Address}/{action=Create}/{id?}");
  });
```

Comment: Remove `[FromBody]` attribute

Comment: Reference [Customize model binding behavior with attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.2#customize-model-binding-behavior-with-attributes)

Comment: `[Route()]` attribute commonly used at over Controller name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First problem: don't use `action="url"`, use ASP.NET Core attributes, these generate the correct URL for you while also ensuring the AntiForgeryToken is present in the form:

```
<form asp-controller="Address" asp-action="Save">
```

Second problem: `[FromBody]` is used for sending data in the body of the request, most commonly as JSON, and you are using Form content.

```
public IActionResult Save(Address address)
```

Third problem: don't use both `[Route]` and `[Http*]`, prefer using only one of them

```
[HttpPost("/Address/Save")]
```

Fourth problem: this configuration means that `/` will go to `Address/Create`, and `/Home` will go to `/Home/Create`, that is a very weird template:

```
template: "{controller=Address}/{action=Create}/{id?}");
```

I would suggest you to keep to the original Index action (or whatever you want to call it) and set your startup URL to `/Address/Create`.

```
template: "{controller=Address}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```